# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource React Django error

Tags: reactjs, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/product/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: This question is not clear and does not provide enough details about what help do you need, how does your setup looks like, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with Django but I know that the error is because you have to enable CORS which will allow you to make api calls to domains other than the source of your call (or on a different port). Check for the documentation to see how to enable CORS.

https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

Answer (score 0):

This error is being caused by your django backend. Here is what you can do to fix it:

1. Install django-cors-headers using pip like @seddouguim suggested
2. Add 'corsheaders' to your installed apps in your django settings.py file
3. At the bottom of the same settings.py file, you can either add a setting called `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST=['localhost:3000']` (or whatever URL you want to add), OR you can set `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` (good for dev but not for production environments)
4. Lastly set `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ("x-requested-with", "content-type", "accept", "origin", "authorization", "x-csrftoken")`

And you should be good to go

Please feel free to let me know if you encounter any other issues

Comment: I already have these settings (except 4),but it has not solved my error, still i am not able to get data from backend.